# Can nginx explicitly close websocket connection when graceful shutdown via nginx -s quit?

Tags: nginx, websocket

I configured a nginx instances as a reverse proxy for a websocket server and established a websocket between client and server, according to the official tutorial https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/.

Then I run `nginx -s quit` to gracefully shut down nginx.

I found that a worker process is always in a status `shutting down..` and I can still send message via the established websocket connection, then the nginx master and worker process will hang up until timeout.

**I'd like to know if nginx supports the function that telling both client and server to close the socket connection on transportation level and exit normally, instead of waiting for the websocket time out.**

Comment: Try adding a `proxy_read_timeout 60s;` to your `proxy_pass` block.

Comment: `proxy_read_timeout` is `60s` by default, http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

Comment: not seen the config in question thats why suggested. May be it was changed. So just to be sure.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you very much for your suggestions. :)

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: @TarunLalwani After the timeout, nginx will exit anyway.

Comment: So I found one directive which may work for you. `worker_shutdown_timeout 5s;` Nginx min version needed 1.11.11.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you very much. Finally, we adopt proxy_read_timeout directive, which can meet our business requirements.